# regex dice roll

Tags: ruby, regex

This is an example question from codefights.com 
The object is to calculate the maximum score for a dice roll. To solve this problem, I have created a regex. It fails for one case (and passes all others):

`pat = /(?<rolls>\d{1,2})?d(?<sides>\d{1,2})(?<sign>\+|\-)?(<mod>\d{1,2}|L)?/`

rules: "4d6-L1d20-10 did4n't expect that"
Output:
47
Expected Output:
38

The only way I can sum that input to 38 is if I consider (4x6) - 6(L in this context https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) Then (ignoring there is no white space) + (1x20). I cannot think of a reason why the total is not 28 instead of 38. (1x20) - 10 is a legit formula according to the rules. I would really appreciate some insight into this problem or an idea on what logic I can use to solve it.

```
def bugsAndBugfixes(rules)
  matches = []
  pat = /(?<rolls>\d{1,2})?d(?<sides>\d{1,2})(?<sign>\+|\-)?(?<mod>\d{1,2}|L)?/
  rules.scan(pat) { matches << $~ }
  result = 0
  matches.each do |match|
    c= Hash[ match.names.zip( match.captures ) ]
    c['rolls'] = 1 unless c['rolls']
    if c['sign'] == '-'
      result+=(c['rolls'].to_i * c['sides'].to_i) - c['mod'].to_i
    else
      result+=(c['rolls'].to_i * c['sides'].to_i) + c['mod'].to_i
    end
  end
result
end
```

end

---

For rules = "Roll d6-3 and 4d4+3 to pick a weapon, and finish the boss with 3d7!",
the output should be
bugsAndBugfixes(rules) = 43.

There are three formulas in the rules.

d6-3 indicates a single roll of a 6-sided die, with 3 subtracted from the result. The maximum number that is possible to get is thus 6 - 3 = 3.
4d4+3 stands for 4 rolls of a 4-sided die, with 3 added to the result. It is possible to get 4 * 4 + 3 = 19 points.
3d7 means 3 rolls of a 7-sided die. The maximum number to obtain with it is 3 * 7 = 21.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend always indenting your code. It'll make it more readable and maintainable, plus you'll find it helps you debug problems. Also, use whitespace surrounding operators and `=`; They help the brain parse the expression. Finally, methods names are snake_case, not camelCase. This is idiomatic and a readability thing.

Comment: now indented. sorry i missed it (it drives me nuts too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bugsAndBugfixes(rules)
    matches = []
    pat = /(?<rolls>\d+)?d(?<sides>\d+)(?<sign>\+|\-)?(?<mod>\d+)?/
    rules.scan(pat) { matches << $~ }
    result = 0
    matches.each do |match|
    c = Hash[ match.names.zip( match.captures ) ]
    c['rolls'] = 1 unless c['rolls'] 
    if c['sign'] == '-'
        tmp=(c['rolls'].to_i * c['sides'].to_i) - c['mod'].to_i
    else
        tmp=(c['rolls'].to_i * c['sides'].to_i) + c['mod'].to_i
    end
    p "#{tmp} #{c}"
    result += tmp
end
result
```

end

Comment: Got the regex working by getting a better custom test. Posting here in case it helps another lost soul: rules = "3d2-1 44d32+22 21d2*1 d3sd3d91ldks 15d6-60 12d12 d5-2 1111d11-111 3d3 oo2d2oo 7d3 1d3 some text 1d33" the output should be 13931

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc(str)      
  n, _, m, sign, p = str.split /\s*/
  tot = n.to_i * m.to_i
  sign ? tot.send(sign, p.to_i) : tot
end 

calc "4d3+3"     #=> 15 
calc "4d3-3"     #=> 9 
calc "4d3"       #=> 12 
calc "4 d 3 + 3" #=> 15
```

Comment: Is `sign` ever going to be `false` here? Testing for `.nil?` seems a little paranoid.

Comment: @tadman, `str` might be simply (say) `"4d3`. In that case `n, _, m, sign, p = str.split /\s*/` #=> ["4", "d", "3"]` and `sign #=> nil` (and `p #=> nil`). `sign #=> nil` tells us we are finished after the second line of the method is executed.

Comment: Oh, I get that, but `nil` vs. `false` isn't an important distinction here, so `.nil?` is sort of redundant since the logical truth is enough. `sign ? tot.send(sign, p.to_i) : tot`

Comment: @tadman, I now see your point, and did an edit. Thanks. Go Jays.